# Can a Daemon process fork child processes in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, daemon, python-daemon

I have a daemon process that keeps on running which I created using runit package. I want daemon process to listen to a table and perform tasks based on the column of the table which says what task it needs to perform.

```
EG: table 'A' has column job_type.
```

I was thinking of forking child processes from this daemon process every time it gets a new task to perform (based on the new row inserted in the table A which daemon listens to).

The multiprocessing module says I can't or shouldn't fork child processes from daemon as if it dies, the children processes are orphaned.

**What is a good approach to achieve that Daemons listens to table, based on column value,forks child processes (all independent of each other) which does the task and goes back to the daemon and dies.**

I need to use some locking mechanism if the child processes are accessing shared data and modifying it..

Answer (score 0):

I assume the daemon process you have is also spawned from a python script which called multiprocess with daemon=true.
In this case the daemon is running implies that your creator process is still running, so you can just send it a message via pipes to spawn a new process for you. If your daemon needs to talk with this, use sockets or any ipc method of your choice.